# runnable Jar file not working,first to third exports is working but several exports dont

Tags: java, jar

its been 2 hours for googling what could be the problem of my exported jar file from eclipse.

My first to third export dont have problem and my jar file runs. But in several exports, the generated jar file is not working already. Help. please.

I have jre and jdk installed. my environment variables are ok.

Comment: I have had also such a problem, for me there were directorys with files I created that doesn't appear in the folder from runnable jar. try if you got such files to add them to the same directory as your runnable ;)

Comment: @Zorian i really appreciate your help. ahmmm, first exports were good. i dont have any folder but the jar file only. it runs. i will try your suggestion. thanks.

Comment: no prob, I was facing this around 2-3h ago and also don't find it on google, so I was lucky to find by myself^^

Comment: @Zorian i export my other application and it works. but my intended project to export doesnt work.

Comment: @Zorian you were right. i copied all the files in the eclipse workspace with the folder where the .jar file is generated/put. It workkkkkkkkkks. THANKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.

Comment: good to hear that it worked ;)